# where is XDG_CACHE_DIR?

Tags: session, gnome-session

I've been suggested that Gnome Podcasts stores the files in

```
XDG_CACHE_DIR/downloads
```

Where is XDG_CACHE_DIR ?

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable should be named XDG_CACHE_**HOME**, not **_DIR**.

From the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

> **$XDG_CACHE_HOME** defines the base directory relative to which user specific non-essential data files should be stored. If $XDG_CACHE_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to **$HOME/.cache** should be used.

Comment: **_DIR** is not part of the specification.

Comment: ok but what is it set to in a Ubuntu session ?

In $HOME/.cache I can't see anything by Podcasts and in the terminal it's not set

Comment: In Ubuntu it is by default not set, so it is `$HOME/.cache`. If the software did not safe anything there you have to ask the developers I guess.